# Can batteries be damaged?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, battery

I have some questions when it comes to draining batteries with low power projects.

I have been making a few low power projects with Arduino Pro Minis running on batteries. Some run on single non-recharchable CR123As while others run on two or three recharchable AAAs. I have removed the regulator and the power led on the Pro Minis, and I have changed the fuses making them run as low as 1.8v (or according to my measurements 1.7v). This way they consume a few µA and should be able to run for years on those batteries.

Now, what started to concern me is that this setup will be able to run the batteries very low. According to the voltage curve of a CR123A, it will be practically drained when reaching 1.7v. The same goes for two or three recharchable NiMH AAAs, that will have an individual voltage of 0.85v or 0.55v. Unless the batteries themselves have a discharge protection built in. In that case there might be no problem at all; I just don't know if batteries such as Eneloops have that.

So my questions are:

1) Do batteries such as CR123As and Eneloops have built in discharge protection so that they stop supplying power when the voltage is too low?

2) If no, will draining a non-rechargable CR123A be dangerous or problematic in any way? And will draining MiMHs down to 0.85v/0.55v hurt the batteries?

3) And, a question that I suppose applies to any battery powered Arduino project: When the supplied voltage drops below the Pro Minis BOD limit, will the Arduino stop using any power, or will it continue draining the batteries until they are completely empty? (In the first case I guess I could stick with the factory set BOD at 2.7v to protect the batteries.)

4) Finally, relating to the first question: Should I try to construct some kind of battery protection in the circuit, or is unnecessary when using CR123A and NiMH batteries?

Comment: Consider posting this on Electrical Engineering SE rather than Arduino SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Do batteries such as CR123As and Eneloops have built in discharge protection so that they stop supplying power when the voltage is too low?

No, they don't.  They just run till there is nothing left.

> 2) If no, will draining a non-rechargable CR123A be dangerous or problematic in any way? And will draining MiMHs down to 0.85v/0.55v hurt the batteries?

A single cell can be run completely flat without problems. NiMH may need some "recovery" to wake them back up again, but shouldn't suffer serious problems (and no safety issues).  However, *batteries* are a different matter: see below.

> 3) And, a question that I suppose applies to any battery powered Arduino project: When the supplied voltage drops below the Pro Minis BOD limit, will the Arduino stop using any power, or will it continue draining the batteries until they are completely empty? (In the first case I guess I could stick with the factory set BOD at 2.7v to protect the batteries.)

It will continue draining power. The BOD is a *reset* circuit - designed to recover the system into a known good state after a dip in the power. A permanent decrease in the input power is beyond the scope of the BOD system.  It will just get stuck in a BOD reset loop and consume all your remaining power.

> 4) Finally, relating to the first question: Should I try to construct some kind of battery protection in the circuit, or is unnecessary when using CR123A and NiMH batteries?

For a single non-rechargeable cell you can just let it run flat. For NiMH you need to protect them.  Here's why (and what I was alluding to above):

---

When you have two or more cells in series (a *battery*) the current flows through all the cells of the battery equally. That is all fine when the cells are all fully charged - however no two cells are precisely the same.

As the battery runs down each cell will approach "empty" at a different time. With a single cell that's not really a problem, since it will just stop providing enough current to run.  However, with multiple cells one cell will run flat before the others. At that point the current provided by the other cells which still have some charge in them will be pushed through the flat cell *backwards*.  It is at that point that the flat cell becomes irrevocably damaged.  Current flowing backwards through the cell will try to *reverse charge* the battery and mess up the internal chemistry beyond recovery.

In the best case scenario, your battery will now have a much lower capacity and need recharging far more often. Worst case scenario: that damaged cell overheats and explodes.

The most prevalent problem that is caused by reverse charging is the depositing of metal crystals on the dielectric (the separator between the two electrodes) in the cell which grow and pierce the dielectric causing short circuits within the cell. There is no way back from that happening.

So you should protect your NiMH batteries from over-discharge by cutting the power to your circuit when the voltage drops below a specific threshold.  You should also recharge all the cells individually, not together in series, or they will end up unbalanced and the same problems of over-discharge can occur.

---

As a side note: I use the terms "cell" and "battery" with their "proper" usage: A *cell* is a single power-producing unit, such as an AA "battery".  A *battery* is a collection of cells.  This is the *proper* usage of the words, not the common usage where *battery* can also be taken to mean *cell*.  I use these terms specifically to differentiate between a single unit and a collection of units because of the major differences in how you need to handle them. It helps prevent confusion if you know that I am talking about just one AA (a cell) or a collection of three AA in series (a battery), for example.

Comment: Wow, thanks, Majenko, that was a quick and brilliantly explained answer. 

The conclusion then would be that I can stop worrying about my project running CR123A cells (thanks for clarifying those terms!) while I need to make protective circuits for my projects with NiMH batteries.

I must admit that I am relatively new to electronics, so please excuse yet another question: What would be a simple way to introduce discharge protection to a low power project? Is it possible without drawing much current? My projects consume 5-30 µa in sleep mode, and I would love to keep them in that range.

Comment: You can measure the power supply voltage directly with the Arduino (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150218055034/http://code.google.com:80/p/tinkerit/wiki/SecretVoltmeter)), and implement a simple "soft power" switch using a P-channel MOSFET (wired so it's normally off, and the Arduino turns it on with a GPIO - use a button to bypass it to turn the system on).  Draws next to nothing, governed by the values of pullup resistors alone.